# mysql not opening due to port number change

Tags: mysql, xampp

Earlier I had xampp and I somehow changed its mysql port number and then recently I uninstalled xampp, now when I installed mysql command line server 5.5 it gives me this error when tried to open through cmd. How to solve.

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if MYSQL service is installed in services.msc In case not, go to services.msc & check if windows firewall is On. if yes, stop it.

Open cmd as an administrator and go to bin folder of your MYSQL installation.
type mysqld --install. It will successfully install service.
Now start the MYSQL services and try to configure the same.